# C# WPF App to read data from a pipe

Tags: c#

I have a C# WPF GUI app (C#App1) which among other things, reads lines from a text file and displays its contents in a text box. I need to extend this to read the piped output data from a C++ console app(C++App2) which is run from the command prompt, and display its contents in the text box in the GUI. Please give insight on how to do this.

For Eg

> cmd>C++App2 | C#App1

Now the GUI C#App1 should display the C++ Output data

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s;
        while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }
}
```

The console.ReadLine will get the data from the output of the C++ program and it will print it back. If you want to handle the data from the C++ app, just remove the Console.WriteLine for something that can handle the string from "s". You might have to set a thread to be able to read from the console while not stopping the GUI in WPF.